# How to pass variable in index.html to react components

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs

I am making a project using Django and React. I fetch the data from Twitter API from Django and I want to show the data in frontend.
I pass the data from django views.py to index.html as a javascript variable. Then I want to present it in the Landing.js in Components folder. I used React router and I Landing and Main page are pages that I am routing to so far. I have not figured out how to pass the data from a single html file to Javascript components in React

Thanks in advance

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<section class="section">
    <div class="container">
          <div id="app" class="columns"><!-- React --></div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.myVar = "{{context.near.text}}";
    //data can be passed from the Django.views.py
    
  </script>

  {% load static %}
  <script src="{% static 'frontend/main.js' %}"></script>
```

```js
//Landing.js js components
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Landing extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(window.myVar); //undefined
        console.log(this.myVVar); //undefined
        
        
    }
    
    render(){
        return (
            <div>

                
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Landing;
```

[This is my tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gb2Sq.png)

[this is context I pass from Django views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.c)

[this is a variable I want to pass to "LANDING" components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QuFt.png)[This is "Landing.js" components I want to show the variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1WJo.png)

Comment: it's possible but don't do this - react is not another template engine - let your app fetch data from your api

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you figured out how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new property in the `window` object maybe `window._DEFAULT_DATA` and pass it the serialized data from Django in your view.

In the head tag in HTML

```
<script>
    window._DEFAULT_DATA = 'Data parsed in string'
 </script>
```

Then when you want to use it, just use `JSON.parse` to have a new JSON.

Comment: Suppose you want to access 'tweets' field in the data, you have to parse like `const data = JSON.parse(window._DEFAULT_DATA);` and access just with `data.tweets`

Comment: Try to make `console.log(window._DEFAULT_DATA)` just after you set it to be sure all is normal!!!

Answer (score 2):

index.html:

```
<script>
localStorage.setItem('data', data)
</script>
```

React component:

```
let data = localStorage.getItem('data')
```